# Different positions in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an sql query which outputs an array the output looks like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [customer_id] => 7
        [language_id] => 1
        [variableitem_id] => 13
        [name] => QUESTION_HEADLINE
        [value] => Bitte geben Sie Ihren Downloadkey ein:
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [customer_id] => 7
        [language_id] => 1
        [variableitem_id] => 15
        [name] => QUESTION_BUTTON
        [value] => Start!
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [customer_id] => 7
        [language_id] => 1
        [variableitem_id] => 6
        [name] => PAGETITLE
        [value] => Steigenberger Hotels and Resorts - Mediathek
    )
)
```

In my controller I get it as

```
$data['variables_data'] = $this->Home_model->getVariables($customer_id, $language_id);
```

Now for different ids in the url like for

```
 localhost/home/user/12 and  localhost/home/user/14
```

the positions of the variable differs

for example in my view when I echo

```
$variable[0]['value']
```

it gives QUESTION_HEADLINE for one user and PAGE_TITLE for the other .
Is it possible to make them same for all of the user like if I echo

```
 $variable[0]['value']
```

it should return me QUESTION_HEADLINE every time and for every user

Code for Home model get_variables function

```
function getVariables($customer_id, $language_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT customers_idcustomers AS customer_id, 
                               languages_idlanguages AS language_id, 
                               variableitems_idvariableitems AS variableitem_id,
                               variableitem AS name, 
                               variabletext AS value
                               FROM variables v
                               LEFT JOIN variableitems vi ON v.variableitems_idvariableitems = vi.idvariableitems
                               WHERE v.customers_idcustomers ='" . $customer_id . "' 
                               AND v.languages_idlanguages =" . $language_id
    );
    $var = $query->result_array();
    return $var;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you write source code of `Home_model->getVariables()` function

Comment: @safarov I added the function code. Have a look at it please

Comment: Your codes look ok. Sorry but dont understand your question. You want to group array by customer and make 1 dimension array or what ?

Comment: yes I want it to be one dimension array

Comment: like this ? [pastebin.com/D01kxB9z](http://pastebin.com/D01kxB9z)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it explicitly, like

`foreach($outArray as $output)
{
$output['name']="Any thing you want";
}`

Answer (score 0):

So , as i understand you want to make reduce your output to one dimension. It can be done with MYSQL also. Here php version:

In your controller

```
$data = $this->Home_model->getVariables($customer_id, $language_id);
$data['variables'] = array(
    'customer_id' => $data[0]['customer_id'],
    'language_id' => $data[0]['language_id'],
    'variableitem_id' => array(),
    'name' => array(),
    'value' => array()
);

foreach($data as $k => $v) {
   $data['variables']['variableitem_id'][] = $v['variableitem_id'];
   $data['variables']['name'][] = $v['name'];
   $data['variables']['value'][] = $v['value'];
}
```

And in your view

```
 echo $variables['value'][2].' '.$variables['value'][3];
 //do whatever you want
```

Comment: what should I write in the array of names and values?

Comment: @Faryal: I think he has just given you an example, you have to implement the rest ......